# Is there a size limit on response size in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am developing an Android App which syncs with a MongoDB server in the backend. The amount of data sent by MongoDB is large and I am not receiving it whole on my client side(Android App). Is there a size limit on responses for HTTP requests in Node.js? If there is, how can I solve this problem?
I am using Node.js + Express.js + MongoDB on my backend.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no size limit on responses sent from a node HTTP server. The amount of memory your application has access to is the only limitation.